# Can't use a protocol as generic argument in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Take a look at this code:

```swift
protocol Renderable {}

protocol Drawing: Renderable {}

class RandomGenericClass<T: Renderable> {
    
    func doSomeStuff(t: T) {}
    
}

let randomGenericClassInstance = RandomGenericClass<Drawing>()
```

I have a Renderable protocol that will have some properties and methods now omitted for simplicity.

Then i have a Drawing protocol which extends Renderable and will be implemented by any concrete class i will need to represent a drawing.

Now i need RandomGenericClass to take as generic argument anything that extends Renderable, in this case a want it to take anything that is a Drawing (which i thought was possibile since Drawing extends Renderable) but i just get the following error

```
Type 'any Drawing' cannot conform to 'Renderable'

Only concrete types such as structs, enums and classes can conform to protocols
```

Coming from Java and other languages i find swift's generics a bit weird, from the error  i understand only concrete types can conform to protocols, then what is the right approach to achieve what i described?

Comment: You cannot create an instance because Drawing is a protocol. You require an instance of a struct or class conforming to drawing.